# How to decode xml with special character by golang

Tags: xml, go

For example, if the xml is simple:

`<p>this is a test xml</p>`

Then I can use struct like this:

`` type Dummy struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"p"`
    Value   string   `xml:",chardata"`
} ``

But if the xml has special character, like

`<p>this is a test < xml & </p>`

I used the same struct and it caused error, and it seems nothing to do with struct, because I use interface{} and it caused error the same.

I read the document of package "encoding/xml" but cannot find the right way.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: & and > are special characters only allowed to appear in their entity forms... it s not a valid xml document.

Comment: You cannot decode non-XML as XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XML is not well-formed. It contain syntax error because character `&` has a special meaning. If you need to insert if as a symbol itself change it with `&amp;`. After parsing it will be replaced back to usual `&`.

The same rule applies to `<` - it should be replaced with `&lt;`.

```
  <p>this is a test <gt; xml &amp; </p>
```

This is the general rule for all XML parsers  and encoders. Any other XML system awaits similar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the error (try it on [golang playground](https://play.golang.org/p/g2FRUmzA7z)), it's telling you the input is not valid XML.

```
XML syntax error on line 1: expected element name after <
```

The text is not allowed to contain plain < or & like that, see the [Character data section of the xml spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#syntax)